# googletag defineslot with shadow dom

Tags: polymer, google-tag-manager, shadow-dom

I would like to add double click ads tags to an element using :

> googletag.defineSlot(adUnitPath, size, opt_div)    Constructs an ad slot
>   with a given ad unit path and size and associates it with the ID of a
>   div element on the page that will contain the ad.

like this :

```
googletag.defineSlot('myslot', [728, 90], 'ad-container')
```

the ad-container div is in a Polymer webcomponent and the application is set with shadow dom enable. The div is not found by googletag api. The publisher console output :

> Slot 'myslot' does not have a container div with id: 'ad-container'.

if app is switch to shady dom, it works.

Is there a way to get googletag with shadow dom ?

Comment: I'm afraid not. Or through a hack: copy (duplicate) the element inside the shadow dom into the normal dom.

Comment: ok .. so i get back to the shady dom for now. thanks

Comment: i think it will never change unless GoogleTag decide to support shadow Dom